# Assigning issue, unable to give or take groups in admin , django

Tags: django

So basically what is happening is that i am trying to stop a user from acessing specific views, for example: admin and so on, unfortunately for some weird reason every time i create a user it receives every group role i created, even tho i didnt even write the code for it. I also cant take out a user from a group or put him in one, when i go inside a user infos. it is worth noting i am using, an abstract user model which may be the cause.
This is how my user admin currently is, this is a new user by the way
[image: This is how the groups part currently is]

And this is how i think it should look like
[image: i am pretty sure it should look like this]
As you can see in the second example the guy is capable of taking out groups and putting then, why is my different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why that happens it turns out the way i setted up, my customuser at admin was lacking a little bit of the capabilities of the default user page, knowing that i just added this lines of code on my admin.py file.

```
from django.contrib.auth import admin as auth_admin
admin.site.register(CustomUser, auth_admin.UserAdmin)
```

Which improved my groups register and now i have those options